# Check if tuple types are subsets of each other

Tags: c++, boost-mpl, boost-hana

Say I have 2 tuples that are not instantiated. Is there an idiomatic way to check if one set is the subset of the other?

If this requires another type instead of `hana::tuple_c`, this is fine as well. Actually, my current input consists of `std::tuple`, but I couldn't get it working either way.

Code that does **NOT** work (but I feel like there should be something similar possible):

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
using namespace boost;

using SetA = hana::tuple_c<int, char, float>;
using SetB = hana::tuple_c<int, float>;

static_assert(
    hana::is_subset( SetB, SetA ),
    ""
);
```

My current workaround uses `boost::mpl` to do an intersection and then compare the results. This works, but I'm interested in a pure `boost::hana` solution:

```
#include <boost/mpl.hpp>
using namespace boost;

using SetA = mpl::set<int, char, float>;
using SetB = mpl::set<int, float>;

using Intersection = typename mpl::copy_if<
    SetA,
    mpl::has_key< SetB, mpl::_1 >,
    mpl::back_inserter< mpl::vector<> >
>::type;

// since Intersection is a vector, subset also needs vector type
using Subset = typename mpl::copy<
    SetB,
    mpl::back_inserter< mpl::vector<> >
>::type;

static_assert(std::is_same<Intersection, Subset>::value, "");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not using `boost::hana` correctly. This will work:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
using namespace boost;

constexpr auto setA = hana::tuple_t<int, char, float>;
constexpr auto setB = hana::tuple_t<int, float>;

// Is `setB` a subset of `setA`? (Yes.)
static_assert(hana::is_subset(setB, setA), "");

// Is `setA` a subset of `setB`? (No.)
static_assert(!hana::is_subset(setA, setB), "");
```

---

Explanation:

[`hana::tuple_t<xs...>`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1tuple.html#aea7b637fbc34b451bd1cef82f1b64b6a) is shorthand notation for a tuple of `hana::type_c` objects.

- ```
  auto x = hana::tuple_t<int, char>;
  // ...is equivalent to...
  auto x = hana::make_tuple(hana::type_c<int>, hana::type_c<char>);
  ```

[`hana::type_c`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1type.html#ae35139e732c4b75e91061513cf445628) objects wrap types into values.

[`hana::is_subset(a, b)`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1Searchable.html#a386ac8af7123ea1e8ea1fa2bbd4cbf3d) checks **if `a` is a subset of `b`**, and not viceversa *(you were checking if `b` was a subset of `a` in your question)*.